# Lots of missing files in debsums output

Tags: debian, troubleshooting, disk-cleanup

I run `debsums -cs` in a machine running Debian Jessie. The output is lots of missing files.

Lots of them (maybe all) has some sort of locale two letters code (like zh, fr, de, and so on).

I have run BleachBit and some Debian tool to make free space some days ago and I suppose this caused the problem.

How should I deal with this? Is suppressing the output possible? Could I re-install locales?

Sample output:

```
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man8/adduser.8.gz (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man8/deluser.8.gz (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man5/deluser.conf.5.gz (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man5/adduser.conf.5.gz (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/adduser.mo (from adduser package)
```

Comment: "some Debian tool to make free space". What tool was that?

Comment: `localepurge` probably...

Comment: @FaheemMitha: It was the standard Debian tool for disk space usage analysis. I think it's `Baobab`

Comment: @StephenKitt: is there a `localeUNpurge`?

Comment: @PierreB no, but see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **remove files** for locales which don't interest you (or anything else for that matter), you should tell `dpkg` about it: that way not only will `debsums` stop complaining about them, but `dpkg` won't even install them in the first place.

Here's what I have, in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/locales`:

```
# Drop locales except English and French
path-exclude=/usr/share/locale/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/en/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/fr/*
path-include=/usr/share/locale/locale.alias

# Drop translated manpages except English and French
path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/man[1-9]/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/en*/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/fr*/*
```

If you adapt this to your setup you should find `debsums` produces much more useful output.

Raphael Hertzog wrote a [blog post](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/11/15/save-disk-space-by-excluding-useless-files-with-dpkg/) about this with a little more detail.

If instead you want to **restore the missing files**, you need to re-install the affected packages:

```
apt-get --reinstall install $(debsums -c 2>&1 | grep -E -o 'from [^ ]* package' | cut -d\  -f2 | sort -u)
```

Comment: Stephen, I used to have `localepurge` installed, but right now I don't. I must have lost it when I did a fresh upgrade. I don't want to reinstall it to test. So, my question is, is this output for `debsums` normal if localepurge is used? And thanks for the `dpkg` config tips, it looks useful.

Comment: @Faheem, it depends on how `localepurge` is set up; but if it's still installed and configured, `debsums` is supposed to take it into account. If Baobab was used instead, the output in the question makes sense.

Comment: The approach you mention makes `localpurge` obsolete though, right?

Comment: @Faheem, yes, it does (and it's better since it doesn't involve installing files then deleting them).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the packages for the missing files. The way  to do so is to retrieve packages names of missing files using `dpkg -S`, then reinstall them with `apt-get`:

```
debsums -cs | grep -E ^debsums | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -rd '\n' -- dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u | xargs -rd '\n' -- apt-get install --reinstall
```